# zsh/bash string to array not working using parentheses

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, zsh

Do you know why the following is not converting string into array?

```
  STR="one two three"
  array=("$STR")

  echo "${array[@]}" # prints: one two three
  echo "len: ${#array[@]}" # prints: len: 1
  echo "item: ${array[2]}" # prints: <nothing>
```

Comment: You are making an array of one string here. What results do you expect other than `zsh` and `bash` not agreeing what the zeroth item of an array might be?

Answer (score 3):

The value of STR is one element in your array due to quoting. You could populate your array like-

```
array=(one two three)
```

Arrays in `zsh` start at 1 not 0 as in `ksh` and `bash`.

Answer (score 3):

In ZSH you can use a [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion). Here, the `s: :` expansion is used to `s`plit the string on   which might be hard to see; we could call it ASCII decimal value 32 or just space.

```
% string="foo bar"
% array=(${(s: :)string})
% print $array[1]
foo
```

The `bash` code elsewhere on this page is not really safe under all conditions. The POSIX shell by default does an auto-split (which here is desired) and auto-glob (which may be very undesirable; if any glob characters at any point get into the `string` and then match files in the current working directory):

```
bash-5.1$ string="who* foo"
bash-5.1$ array=($string)
bash-5.1$ echo ${array[@]}
whoops.app whoops.png whoops.txt foo
bash-5.1$ printf '%s\n' ${array[@]}
whoops.app
whoops.png
whoops.txt
foo
bash-5.1$ ls whoops.*
whoops.app      whoops.png      whoops.txt
```

Surprise!!

(ZSH is not POSIX compliant so does not do the unquoted variable auto-split auto-glob thing (by default), thank goodness.)

Comment: Nice call out of the need for [noglob](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12225245/475228) in many command line scripting situations. +1

Comment: I dabbled with `noglob` for a while then was like why don't I just use ZSH or some other language...

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be working:

bash

```
 array=($STR) # removed expansion ""
```

zsh

```
eval "array=($STR)"
```